# How to tell ScheduledExecutorService to ignore overlapping executions after resuming computer from suspension/hibernation

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduled-tasks, scheduledexecutorservice, hibernation

I've got a thread in charge of periodically refreshing some remote service queries response cache every 10-15 minutes.

The problem is when a client's machine resumes from sleep the refresh task executes sleep time / refresh period times instead of just once.

It's not overloading the server or anything, but it is inefficient. How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the task is scheduled at a fixed rate via the [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html), change the task to a [self-scheduling task](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23231576/3080094).
In this manner there is always only 1 task waiting to be executed.

Comment: I had forgotten about this question, but yes; this is what I ended up doing. It is good to have some confirmation though, because I haven't got a lot of experience on this, and I was worried that scheduling this way could be a bad practice (something like: what if there is an abnormal termination I didn't account for, like not enough resources to execute the update thread, and the next update doesn't get scheduled?), and so I thought that maybe the standard practice was something different I wasn't finding anywhere because I didn't have a name for it.